# C++ classes in separate file

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to learn how to make classes in C++ where I use a header file, a .cpp file that contains the class function definitions, and a main .cpp file. Here is what I have (taken from an example)

in class.h

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  void foo();
  int bar;
};
```

in class.cpp

```
#include "class.h"
using namespace std;
void MyClass::foo()
{
    cout<< "test";
}
```

in main.cpp

```
#include "class.h" 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  MyClass a;
  a.foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling the main.cpp results in this error: 
   [Linker error] C:\:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `MyClass::foo()' 
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Do I need to compile the class.cpp or class.h? Am I missing a way of linking class.h with class.cpp? If so how do I link them?

Comment: `using namespace std;` is more typing than the one `std::` you need for `cout`. You should learn to avoid it in the future.

Comment: If you tell us what compiler / IDE you are using, you could get more specific answers on how to make this work, but essentially you need to compile the cpp files and *link* them into your executable.

Comment: I'm using Dev-C++ 5.2.0.1

Answer (score 5):

You need to compile the implementation files into object files and link them together. The following is an example for when you are using `g++`:

```
g++ -c class.cpp -o class.o
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ class.o main.o -o main
./main
```

In reality, you would add more options like `-std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this on Linux shell using `g++`

**Compile** Create object files of `main.cpp` and `class.cpp` called `main.o` and `class.o`

```
g++ -c class.cpp   

g++ -c main.cpp
```

**Linking** the object codes `main.o` and `class.o` to create executable file called `program`

```
g++ -o program main.o class.o
```

then run the `program` executable file

```
./program
```

Comment: I'm using windows and very new, I'm not even sure what g++ is.

Comment: which IDE are you using in Windows??

Answer (score 1):

You are likely to be compiling only main.cpp and not class.cpp.

What command are you using to generate the output ?

This should work fine :

```
g++ class.cpp main.cpp -o class
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine
I tried the code in my Compiler

MyClass.h

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    void foo();
    int bar;
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"

using namespace std;
void MyClass::foo()
{
    cout<< "test";
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MyClass a;
    a.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Ive tried the code in Xcode.
Its working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use compiler option `-I<dir of .h file>` while compiling .cpp file. Compile both the .cpp files